# SSL session resumption not work for TLSv1.3 with openssl on client side

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.3

I'm using the following code to resume TLS sessions as a client with openssl

```
//on ssl connected
SSL_SESSION * s = SSL_get1_session(ssl);
if (s != this->m_clientsession)
{
    cerr << "New session applied: " << this->m_clientsession << " -> " << s << endl;
    if (this->m_clientsession)
    {
        SSL_SESSION_free(this->m_clientsession);
    }
    this->m_clientsession = s;
}
else
{
    cerr << "Resuming with existing session: " << s << endl;
    SSL_SESSION_free(s);
}

//on creating new ssl object
SSL * ssl = SSL_new(this->m_ctx);
if (this->m_clientsession)
{
    SSL_set_session(ssl, this->m_clientsession);
}
```

It works fine on TLS v1.2, including when restrained to TLS v1.2 by `SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version`. But sessions can not be resumed on TLS v1.3, it prints "new session" and makes a full handshake every time. Is there other resuming mechanisms on TLS v1.3?

- I've checked the return of SSL_set_session, it is 1
- OpenSSL 3.0.9

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Sessions, where it states *"The old SSL_get1_session() and similar APIs may not operate as expected for client applications written for TLSv1.2 and below. ...."* . It also provides information about how to properly deal with it so that it works with TLS 1.3